# How to display an image in the terminal with Java

Tags: java, image, terminal, printing

I'm creating a command line app in Java and wanted to know if it was possible to output an image in the terminal. Looked up online but could not find anything...

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what terminal you use, but most do not have the ability to display images

Comment: @TimMoore That's what I thought... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

### You can't output an image in the terminal with Java.

The closest you can get is to output [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art), in which case,
you could use something like TEXT-IMAGE.com to generate a set of characters that can be outputted to the terminal to resemble a image.

Answer (score 1):

You can display an image in the Terminal if your terminal accepts the *"Inline Images Protocol"* a.k.a. OSC codes. It is basically a few bytes of header, a base64-encoded PNG image and a couple of bytes to mark the end of the sequence.

Example [here](https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html).

There is a similar tool called `showimg` and its source is [here](https://github.com/mintty/utils/blob/master/showimg).

---

There is also a package called `imgcat` on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/imgcat/) which works really well and you can install with:

```
pip install imgcat
```